# How to debug no moderation_state on revision

Tags: 8, workflows

I have a custom entity (not written by me) that I need to debug.  It's currently crashing when editing the Entity because there is no moderation_state on the default revision.  I'm new with both: revisions and content_moderation.  Is there a place in core where I should be looking to find example content entities, or does anyone know a good way to debug this?

Currently, the crash happens in ModerationInformation::isDefaultRevisionPublished.  There are 5 states available in the entity that's stumping me, so I'm not sure why the moderation_state isn't being brought back on the entity.

Thanks.